# If websocket handshake completes successfully should I see an onopen event in my client?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, phpwebsocket

First if you could tell me if there is something here that is wrong :

**client:**

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090/websocket_server.php');// ws://echo.websocket.org/echo
console.log(ws);

ws.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection open...", e);

    ws.send("Hello WebSocket!");
};

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    if(typeof e.data === "string"){
        console.log("String message received", e, e.data);
    } else {
        console.log("Other message received", e, e.data);
    }
};

ws.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("WebSocket Error: " , e);
};


ws.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection closed", e);
};
```

**server:**

```
<?php
defined('KEY_SUFFIX') ? null : define('KEY_SUFFIX', "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($sock, 'localhost', 9090);
socket_listen($sock);

while (true) {

    $client = socket_accept($sock) or die('socket_accept returned false');;

    //$buf = socket_read($client, 1024);
    $buf = null;$key=null;
    while ( $line = socket_read($client, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ) ) {
        $buf .= $line;
        if ( strpos($line, 'Sec-WebSocket-Key')!== false ) {
            $key = substr($line, 19);
        } else 
        if ( strpos($line, 'User-Agent')!== false ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //echo $buf;

    $sha1 = SHA1($key.KEY_SUFFIX, true);
    $accept = base64_encode($sha1);

    $write  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\n";
    $write .= "Upgrade: websocket\n";
    $write .= "connection: Upgrade\n";
    $write .= "Sec-Websocket-Accept: $accept\n";
    //$write .= "Sec-Websocket-Extensions: extension\n";

    socket_write( $client, $write, strlen($write) );

}
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

I run the php script in this way:
`F:\xampp\php\php -q D:\websocket_server.php`

**Question:**
Suppose if It's all correct, I keep looking at chrome debugger network section and It's pending and I expected that after this process I should see an onopen event in js console,
what is going on? Am I expecting wrong?
Should the connection between sever and client go from 0 state to 1 state after this process or It needs more work to establish an open state?

Comment: I hope I explained it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the problems:**
**mistakes:**
**1:** reading the last character in the line of the sec-websocket-key which made the calculation of the sec-websocket-accpet wrong on line 18
**2:** Didn't know 2 things about response header : one is that you need to put `\r\n` at the end of each line not just `\n` and seccond is that you need to put two `\r\n\r\n` after the last line of header, it just doesn't work if it's not two. (lines: 30-33)
Now it initiates an onopen event in client.

```
<?php
    defined('KEY_SUFFIX') ? null : define('KEY_SUFFIX', "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_time_limit(0);
    ob_implicit_flush();

    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_bind($sock, 'localhost', 9090);
    socket_listen($sock);

    while (true) {

        $client = socket_accept($sock) or die('socket_accept returned false');;

        //$buf = socket_read($client, 1024);
        $buf = null;$key=null;
        while ( $line = socket_read($client, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ) ) {
            $buf .= $line;
            if ( strpos($line, 'Sec-WebSocket-Key')!== false ) {
                $key = substr($line, 19, 24); // <== mistake num 1 here
            } else 
            if ( strpos($line, 'User-Agent')!== false ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        //echo $buf;

        $sha1 = SHA1($key.KEY_SUFFIX, true);
        $accept = base64_encode($sha1);

        //mistake num 2 here
        $write  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
        $write .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
        $write .= "connection: Upgrade\r\n";
        $write .= "Sec-Websocket-Accept: $accept\r\n\r\n";


        socket_write( $client, $write, strlen($write) );

    }
    socket_close($sock);
?>
```